# Theta functions, a natural basis.

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, theta-functions

Let $L$ be the principal polarization of an abelian variety $A$. Some people say that the theta functions with characteristics form a natural basis of the global section $\Gamma(A,L^{\otimes n})$ for $n>0$. In what sense are they "natural"?

Comment: In the sense that, writing $A=\mathbb{C}^n/\Gamma$, these sections come from holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}^n$ that satisfy suitable properties of quasi-periodicity with respect to the lattice $\Gamma$.